# How to translate the sphere along y-axis (it just go up, so not come down on translation) and how to deform

Tags: javascript, webgl

how to move an object in up and down and make it deform when it touch the roof and bottom ?

I have created a sphere which rotates and moves just up infinitely by translating along y-axis but now i have to move it down and i want it to deform when it collide up and bottom, Now my question are:
  (1) how can i make my sphere move up and down on y axis ?
  (2) How to deform when it touch the top ? and recover same shape back as the contact is finished with top or bottom while moving up and down.

My code for rotating sphere is(I have followed Lesson 11 on Git Hub tutorials on this link https://github.com/gpjt/webgl-lessons/blob/master/lesson11/index.html):

```
 var newRotationMatrix = mat4.create();
        mat4.identity(newRotationMatrix);          
        mat4.rotate(newRotationMatrix, degToRad(2 / 10), [0, 1, 0]);
        mat4.multiply(newRotationMatrix, [1,0,0], moonRotationMatrix);
        gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, moonVertexIndexBuffer.numItems, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

The full function is :

```
function tick()
        {
            requestAnimFrame(tick);
            gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
            gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            mat4.perspective(45, gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 100.0, pMatrix);

            gl.uniform1i(shaderProgram.useLightingUniform, false);
            mat4.identity(mvMatrix);
            mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [0, 0, -6]);
            mat4.multiply(mvMatrix, moonRotationMatrix);
            gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
            gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, moonTexture);
            gl.uniform1i(shaderProgram.samplerUniform, 0);
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, moonVertexPositionBuffer);
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, moonVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, moonVertexTextureCoordBuffer);
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute, moonVertexTextureCoordBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, moonVertexNormalBuffer);
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexNormalAttribute, moonVertexNormalBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, moonVertexIndexBuffer);
            setMatrixUniforms();

          /*rotation part is below*/
            var newRotationMatrix = mat4.create();
            mat4.identity(newRotationMatrix);          
            mat4.rotate(newRotationMatrix, degToRad(2 / 10), [0, 1, 0]);
            mat4.multiply(newRotationMatrix, [1,0,0], moonRotationMatrix);
            gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, moonVertexIndexBuffer.numItems, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

        }
```

What to add in this code that such that it will rotate and must touch top and bottom (letssay which are at the distance of 250 and -250 fromn the center along y-axis-as the motion has to be along y-axis) 
and how to deform it when the sphere touches 250 while going up  and -250 whil going down and recover immediately as the contact between the sphere and top or bottom is finished, and this process should repeat infinitely.

**EDIT:**

In this question moonVertexIndexBuffer contains the vertex of square in the tick function. 
This my initfuffer function

```
function initBuffers(latitudeBands, longitudeBands)
        {           
            var radius = 1;
            var vertexPositionData = [];
            var normalData = [];
            var textureCoordData = [];
            for (var latNumber = 0; latNumber <= latitudeBands; latNumber++)
            {
                var theta = latNumber * Math.PI / latitudeBands;
                var sinTheta = Math.sin(theta);
                var cosTheta = Math.cos(theta);
                for (var longNumber = 0; longNumber <= longitudeBands; longNumber++)
                {
                    var phi = longNumber * 2 * Math.PI / longitudeBands;
                    var sinPhi = Math.sin(phi);
                    var cosPhi = Math.cos(phi);
                    var x = cosPhi * sinTheta;
                    var y = cosTheta;
                    var z = sinPhi * sinTheta;
                    var u = 1 - (longNumber / longitudeBands);
                    var v = 1 - (latNumber / latitudeBands);
                    normalData.push(x);
                    normalData.push(y);
                    normalData.push(z);
                    textureCoordData.push(u);
                    textureCoordData.push(v);
                    vertexPositionData.push(radius * x);
                    vertexPositionData.push(radius * y);
                    vertexPositionData.push(radius * z);                   
                }
            }
            alert("vertexPositionData:" + vertexPositionData);
            var indexData = [];
            for (var latNumber = 0; latNumber < latitudeBands; latNumber++) {
                for (var longNumber = 0; longNumber < longitudeBands; longNumber++) {
                    var first = (latNumber * (longitudeBands + 1)) + longNumber;
                    var second = first + longitudeBands + 1;
                    indexData.push(first);
                    indexData.push(second);
                    indexData.push(first + 1);
                    indexData.push(second);
                    indexData.push(second + 1);
                    indexData.push(first + 1);
                    //console.log("four points for iteration" + latNumber, +longNumber + " are " + "1: " + first + "2 :" + (first + 1) + "3: " + (second) + "4 :" + (second + 1));
                }
            }
            moonVertexNormalBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, moonVertexNormalBuffer);
            gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(normalData), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
            moonVertexNormalBuffer.itemSize = 3;
            moonVertexNormalBuffer.numItems = normalData.length / 3;

            moonVertexTextureCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, moonVertexTextureCoordBuffer);
            gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(textureCoordData), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
            moonVertexTextureCoordBuffer.itemSize = 2;
            moonVertexTextureCoordBuffer.numItems = textureCoordData.length / 2;
                       ///
            moonVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, moonVertexPositionBuffer);
            gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertexPositionData), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
            moonVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
            moonVertexPositionBuffer.numItems = vertexPositionData.length / 3;

            moonVertexIndexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, moonVertexIndexBuffer);
            gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indexData), gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
            moonVertexIndexBuffer.itemSize = 1;
            moonVertexIndexBuffer.numItems = indexData.length;
        }

        function tick()
        {
            requestAnimFrame(tick);
            gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
            gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            mat4.perspective(45, gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 100.0, pMatrix);
            // var lighting = false;
            gl.uniform1i(shaderProgram.useLightingUniform, false);

            /*I removed some part here */

            mat4.identity(mvMatrix);
            mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [0, 0, -6]);
            mat4.multiply(mvMatrix, moonRotationMatrix);
            gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
            gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, moonTexture);
            gl.uniform1i(shaderProgram.samplerUniform, 0);
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, moonVertexPositionBuffer);
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, moonVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, moonVertexTextureCoordBuffer);
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute, moonVertexTextureCoordBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, moonVertexNormalBuffer);
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexNormalAttribute, moonVertexNormalBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, moonVertexIndexBuffer);
            setMatrixUniforms();

            var newRotationMatrix = mat4.create();
            mat4.identity(newRotationMatrix);
            mat4.rotate(newRotationMatrix, degToRad(2 / 10), [0, 1, 0], newRotationMatrix);
            mat4.multiply(newRotationMatrix, moonRotationMatrix, moonRotationMatrix);

            gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, moonVertexIndexBuffer.numItems, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

        }
```

This is my vertex shader:

```
 <script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
        attribute vec3 aVertexNormal;
        attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;
        uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
        uniform mat4 uPMatrix;
        uniform mat3 uNMatrix;
        uniform vec3 uAmbientColor;
        uniform vec3 uLightingDirection;
        uniform vec3 uDirectionalColor;
        uniform bool uUseLighting;
        varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
        varying vec3 vLightWeighting;
        void main(void) {
        gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
        vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
        if (!uUseLighting) {
        vLightWeighting = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        } else {
        vec3 transformedNormal = uNMatrix * aVertexNormal;
        float directionalLightWeighting = max(dot(transformedNormal, uLightingDirection), 0.0);
        vLightWeighting = uAmbientColor + uDirectionalColor * directionalLightWeighting;
        }
        }
    </script>
```

And this is initshaders function

```
 function initShaders()
        {
            var fragmentShader = getShader(gl, "shader-fs");
            var vertexShader = getShader(gl, "shader-vs");
            shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
            gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
            gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
            gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);
            if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
                alert("Could not initialise shaders");
            }
            gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);
            shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
            gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute);
            shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aTextureCoord");
            gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute);
            shaderProgram.vertexNormalAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexNormal");
            gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexNormalAttribute);
            shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uPMatrix");
            shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uMVMatrix");
            shaderProgram.nMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uNMatrix");
            shaderProgram.samplerUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uSampler");
            shaderProgram.useLightingUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uUseLighting");
            shaderProgram.ambientColorUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uAmbientColor");
            shaderProgram.lightingDirectionUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uLightingDirection");
            shaderProgram.directionalColorUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uDirectionalColor");
        }
```

**I am not able to understand how to move it up and down infinitely(translate it along y axis) as we have all the squares in an array, because sphere is made of squares (depending upon latitude and longitude passed in initBuffers() function)  **

**MY try is this (but sphere just go up infinitely, never come back down, how to bring it down)?**

```
   var translation = [0, 0.5,0];
 function tick()
        {
          ....//I am elminating the code which was shown previously
          var translationMatrix = makeTranslation(translation[0], translation[1], translation[2]);
            mat4.multiply(moonRotationMatrix, translationMatrix, moonRotationMatrix);
        }
 function makeTranslation(tx, ty, tz) {

            return [
               1, 0, 0, 0,
               0, 1, 0, 0,
               0, 0, 1, 0,
               tx, ty, tz, 1
            ];
        }
```

**EDIT2: My try for scaling for deformation, after the first answer :**
In the vertex shader i kept uniform as suggested like this:

```
 <script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        uniform  vec4 uScaleY;
        void main(void) {
        gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
         }
        }
    </script>
```

And in initshader() i do this :

```
shaderProgram.uScaleYAttribute = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uScaleY");
```

In setuniform i do this :

```
var yScale =[0,1,0];
  function setMatrixUniforms()
  {
            gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.uScaleYAttribute, false, yScale);
  }
```

And in my tick() i try to do this :

```
  var newRotationMatrix = mat4.create();
        mat4.identity(newRotationMatrix);
        mat4.rotate(newRotationMatrix, degToRad(2 / 10), [0, 1, 0]);
        mat4.multiply(newRotationMatrix, moonRotationMatrix, moonRotationMatrix);
        translateMatrix = translation(translate[0], translate[1], translate[2]);
        mat4.multiply(moonRotationMatrix, translateMatrix,moonRotationMatrix);
        var maxY =1.5;
        var moonPosY = moonRotationMatrix[3 * 4 +1];
        if (moonPosY > maxY || moonPosY < (-maxY))
        {
            translate[1] *= -1;
        }

        var maxDiff = 0.05;
        var minDiff = 0.01;
        var diff = Math.abs(moonPosY - maxY);

        if (diff < maxDiff)//sphere when go up
        {
            yScale = 1 - (minDiff - diff) * 0.1;
        }
            /*
        else if (moonPosY > (-maxDiff)) // scaling when sphere come down
        {
            yScale = 1 - (minDiff - diff) * 0.1;
        }
        */
        gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, moonVertexIndexBuffer.numItems, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

And the scaling do not work for deformation along y-axis while up and down touch of sphere at top and bottom, whats wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `tick` so that it keeps track of the total translation and reverse the translation vector used when the threshold is met.

It'd be something like:

```
var maxY = 100;
var moonPosY = moonRotationMatrix[/*row*/ 3 * 4 + /*col*/ 1];

if (moonPosY < maxY || moonPosY < (-maxY)) {
    translation = translation.map(a => -a);
    // or simply
    // translation[1] *= -1;
    // if you want to reverse it just on Y axis
}
```

To deform it, it depends on the deformation you want, but if you simply want to squash it along Y axis, you can add a uniform to your vertex shader for Y-scale and fill it with something like:

```
var yScale = 1;
var maxDiff = 10;

var diff = Math.abs(moonPosY - maxY);

if (diff < maxDiff) { 
    yScale = 1 - (minDiff - diff) * 0.1;
}
```

Comment: thankyou so much for for up and down movement it is working like heaven :) . for the deformation, i am trying your logic as it works i will mark your answer, till then please survive with +1 to your answer.. Thanks again :)

Comment: please see the edit of question, deformation is not working, i have updated my code for it, i am not able to know what i have done wrong, i tried to follwo your approach. Could you please let me know what i am doing wrong and please update your answer accordingly so that i will mark you as answer (the first part was working for me but not the second one)

Comment: Also what is this minDiff ? also i am not able to uderstand your logic of second answer, actually i want to deform it like a ball when collide a wall.

Comment: Thanks for ur answers, the first one could work but for second one i used another way of doing, i created a scaling matrix and mutiplies the scaling matrix with orginal when i touch the top and bottom and then again mutiply to recover the orginal shape along y-axis. If you know other way ? you are most welcome to write here, still i mark you as asnwer for the first part.